# Detect form changes in Angular when using updateOn:'submit'

Tags: angular

I'm trying to detect if/when the user makes any changes in an Angular form field, so I can warn the user that they have changes outstanding if/when they try to leave the page prematurely (e.g. by pressing a cancel button).

I have a custom directive on my form element, which works like this:

```
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
  this.ngForm.valueChanges.subscribe(_ => {
    if (this.ngForm.dirty) {
      this.myService.recordDirtyForm(...);
    }
  });
}
```

This was all working fine, until I added this to my form element:

```
 [ngFormOptions]="{updateOn: 'submit'}"
```

**I can see *why* this no longer works** - the form is no longer updated until it's submitted, so my code above is not able to detect the user's changes.

**My question is *how* can I *make* it work?** (or at least, achieve a similar result)

I *want* my validation to be delayed until the user submits - hence the `updateOn` setting - but I *also* want to be able to easily detect when the user has unsubmitted changes.

Are these two things mutually exclusive in Angular? Or am I just missing something? (I'm hoping the latter...)

Comment: so you want to wait to detect any changes until after a user submits, but you want to detect changes as the user continues with everything? I would say remove the `updateOn` option and just have a separate function for submitting. maybe even adding an `originalForm` for you to fall back to until a user submits the current changes

Comment: It's really the validation that I want to delay, but Angular doesn't make a separation between validating and updating the form. I have various validation rules set on the form fields, and don't want those firing until the user presses submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can observe change event outside of angular form utilities, for example you can create a custom directive like this

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[customOnChange]'
})
export class CustomOnChangeDirective {

  private el: HTMLInputElement;

  constructor(
    private elementRef: ElementRef,
    private control: NgControl // You can even use the NgControl features
  ) {}

  @HostListener('input', ['$event'])
  onchange(event:any) {
    // HERE you can do your logic
  }
}
```

or even better to debounce the changes you can use `fromEvent` from `rxjs`

```
ngOnInit() {
  fromEvent(this.el.nativeElement, 'input')
  .pipe(debounceTime(200), distinctUntilChanged())
  .subscribe(() => /* Your logic */ )
}
```

Just remember not to `unsubscribe` the subscription on destroy.

Comment: Thanks Mehdi! I came up with a very similar idea in the end, before I saw your answer. Just trying to decide whether I should really be listening for 'input', 'change' or both. I haven't bothered with the debounce, because my event logic is very simple and starts with a boolean check which will fail most of the time, and therefore has less overhead than using Rxjs.

Comment: The input event is fired every time the value of the element changes. This is unlike the change event, which only fires when the value is committed, such as by pressing the enter key, selecting a value from a list of options, and the like.

Comment: Yeah. I don't want this to fire when changes are made by the code though - only when changes are made by the user. And the user can't leave the page without leaving the field first, so I think 'change' should be sufficient.